# showing loading image (hour glass) over a div when data is loading in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on AngularJS application.In the application one of the DIV is displaying grid data. What I want is, when the grid is loading data, system should show the loading image on top of the div & when the data is loaded, it should remove that image.

If I follow the classic way, when data load event is triggered, we can manually show the image on top of the div and when data is fully loaded, we can manually hide the loading image.

Can we automate this process and leave it to AngularJS or any other library to decide when to show and when to hide the loading image. Something like, as long as inner HTML of DIV is getting modified, it should display the loading image.

Comment: How is your grid data getting the data?  From an http request?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can automate this process and leave it to AngularJS using data bindings.

```
<i class=loading-icon ng-if=!ctrl.data.length></i>


app.controller("ctrl", function ($http) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.data = [];

    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
        ctrl.data = data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML add `data-ng-if="isLoading"` to the loading div, then in the js where you load the data set `scope.isLoading` as true at the before making the request and on load complete set it to false.